# JAXB marshal/unmarshal - ing SWT.Image or AWT BufferedImage

Tags: image, jaxb, swt, awt

I am trying to marshal with jaxb an object which contains an Image, and afterwards unmarshalling it (i.e. save/load).

Is there a way to store that image?

I am trying to create a function which returns the byte array describing the swt.image imagedata, but once I marked it as an @XmlElement, the process of storing it fails throwing an Exception like this:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
JAXB annotation is placed on a method that is not a JAXB property
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement()
```

Also, I have tested to convert the SWT.Image to a AWT.BufferedImage, but I still get the same Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception indicates that you have placed an annotation on a method that isn't an accessor (get/set method).  Below is an example using a `java.awt.Image` property:

**Root**

```
package forum9094655;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private Image image;

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9094655;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        Image image = new BufferedImage(1,1,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        root.setImage(image);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <image>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAADElEQVR42mNgYGAAAAAEAAHI6uv5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC</image>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Blaise, The problem is that I am forced to use SWT Images, and I can only create the accessor functions referencing AWT BufferedImages. Is there a way to tell JAXB that it has to lookup at those functions?

Comment: @JosepRodríguezLópez - You can use an `XmlAdapter` to handle any types that JAXB doesn't recognize.  An `XmlAdapter` converts from a type that JAXB doesn't know how to map, into a type it does.  Here is a link to an example where this is done for Joda-Time: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html